# Can nasal irrigation help for chronic sinusitis?

Tags: treatment, treatment-options, sinus

CT revealed chronic inflammation of the paranasal sinuses. In addition to regular treatment (septoplasty, etc.), multiple ENT specialists recommend daily nasal irrigation e.g., with Irigasin (NaCl solution).

However, I have read a counter-opinion of one doctor that:

> There are no waters and sinus cleansing drugs! Is the gibberish of TV commercials of worthless and sometimes harmful preparations. There is no possibility to administer drugs to the inside of the sinuses except for the surgery called puncture or sinus rinsing after the operation of a special connection for this purpose with the nose.

Is there any research confirming that sinus irrigation helps for chronic sinusitis?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Please clarify to make sure: sinus irrigation or nasal irrigation?

Comment: @LangLangC This page: https://www.compoundingcenter.com/sinus-irrigation-vs-sinus-nebulization-whats-the-difference/ says "Sinus irrigation, also called nasal irrigation". Isn't that the same thing then?

Comment: In daily parlance they are, in exact terms they are not. Nasal is quite effective for a number of uses, directly targeting just the sinuses less so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The American Rhinologic Society says:

> [**Nasal/Sinus Irrigation**](http://care.american-rhinologic.org/irrigation)
> **Conclusions:**
> Recent research has confirmed that sinus and nasal irrigations with salt water are helpful. Multiple devices are available for delivery however the high volume and positive pressure methods seem to work the best. Both the irrigation device and the water source have the potential for contamination and thus proper sterilization of both is critical to the safe and effective use of irrigations. Medicated irrigations are being used more commonly and may improve our ability to treat chronic sinusitis.

Sometimes surgery is needed to properly reach the actual sinuses and simple salt solutions might not be enough to really treat acute symptoms in some cases.

It should be noted that the longtime daily use *might* also have some small detrimental effects (most research shows benefits), despite heeding all precautions, depending on the goals of this intervention:

> [**Neti Pot, Nasal Irrigation Pros and Cons**](https://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/neti-pot-nasal-irrigation-pros-and-cons#1)
> Cons of Nasal Irrigation
>
> Using nasal irrigation to clear stuffed sinuses can be helpful from time to time for relieving symptoms, but a study presented at the American College of Allergy, Asthma, and Immunology in 2009 shows that it may actually be counterproductive when used regularly over the long term. The study showed that patients who used nasal saline irrigation for a year and then stopped using it for a year had a 62% lower incidence of sinusitis during the year in which they stopped.

It is worth a try if the dosage (of the salt or meds) is well measured, the water luke warm, and the water and other equipment clean. Unless *your* doctor advises strictly otherwise.